# No puedo subir imágenes al servidor de mi página

Tags: php, .htaccess, permisos

Cuando trato de subir una imagen desde la pc, puedo hacerlo. Sin embargo, desde el celular, si la imagen es muy pesada o es sacada con la cámara de mi celular, me aparece un mensaje de error que dice que no hay memoria suficiente. Qué puede estar sucediendo? Las carpetas de imágenes tienen permisos 777, y el htacess tiene límite de subida de fotos de 10Mb (lo cual es una bestialidad). No entiendo cual puede ser el problema.

Éste es el mensaje de error:

[image: mensaje de error]

Comment: Es tu móvil amigo, lo se por que ya me sucedió.

Comment: Exactamente, era por el celular. Gracias igual!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un problema puede ser que el las configuraciones de `php` tengas un buffer inferior al que requiere las imágenes para ser procesadas.

Comment: Y, en caso de ser eso, cómo podría solucionarlo? Reafirmo, desde la pc no hay problema alguno; desde el celular, sí.

Comment: Y no estoy probando en localhost, sino directamente en el servidor permanente (el cual es premium empresarial)

Comment: madre santa x.x no vi esa parte del PC, en ese caso, intenta cerrar todas las aplicaciones del móvil y deja solamente el navegador, a ver que sucede.

Comment: Ahora estoy descargando el du speed booster para limpiar la ram y los archivos basura para ver que sucede. Y ya cerré todas las apps. Cuando termino te digo que pasó.

Comment: dale, estaré online unos minutos más :D

Comment: Sigue igual... :/

Comment: Se solucionó solo. Creo que era el celular. Gracias igualmente!

Comment: Si cambiaste de celular y funcionó, podríamos decir que lo era, sin embargo si utilizaste el mismo celular ya me picó la curiosidad de saber por qué? y bueno, me alegra que se solucionara :D saludos

Comment: Gracias por la buena onda! Si, era el mismo celuar. Yo creo que tiene que ver con el navegador movil. Igualmente por ahora sigue funcionando bien